# Re-authenticating Twitter to Facebook link without losing posted tweets

Tags: facebook, twitter

I had to change my Facebook and Twitter password. Now my tweets do no longer appear on my Facebook-page.

When opening my Twitter settings, I see two Facebook apps. One is linked, the other is not and says something like 'reauthentication'. When clicking that button, it gives an error. I have not yet tried disabling the other Facebook-app, because I am scared of losing my old tweets that are on my Facebook-page.

What is the best option for me, *without* losing my old tweets that are on my page?

Answer (score 2):

Login both accounts (Facebook and Twitter) separately and change the password for both. Then unlink the accounts from each other. You will not lose your tweets. Later you can link your accounts again.

[Using Twitter with Facebook](https://support.twitter.com/articles/31113).